# Ragged2e: Break between paragraphs

Tags: ragged2e

When I use the package ragged2e, the break between paragraphs disappears. I am new to LaTeX, so I might have missed something elementary, but I cannot figure out how to get an empty line between paragraphs using this package. I have tried to make a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight

\begin{document}

This is the first sentence. This is the sentencethatislong. \\
Line break. Works fine. \\

New paragraph. Does not work. No space between paragraphs.

\end{document}
```

Best, Nikolaj

Comment: You shouldn't put ``\\`` just before a paragraph break. And, by the way, what space do you want? The `\parskip` is usually zero. If you want some space you need to tell latex, for instance using the `parskip` package. Or you can also use `scrartcl` class with `parskip=half`.

Comment: Thank you. I just browsed through some books and articles, and you're right. But I do have one short line of text where I want space before and after. Is that not possible with ragged2e?

Comment: You mean you want to center it? `\begin{center} … \end{center}`? Or is it a quote? Of course you can center it.

Comment: Perfect. I used {quote} to make it work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What space do you want? The `\parskip` is usually zero. If you want some space you *need* to tell latex, for instance using the `parskip` package. Or you can also use `scrartcl` class with `parskip=half`.

By the way, you shouldn't put `\\` just before a paragraph break.

Here are two examples.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn,a4paper,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{parskip}
\RaggedRight

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image]